# Delete a row from Parse.com using android studio

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a table with two attributes: a name and a number. I have editext into which a user enters a name and I should be able to delete the row containing that name.

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all use:

```
String text = edittext.getText().toString();
```

After that, use this query:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(TableName);
query.whereEqualTo("Name", text);
query.getInBackground(objectId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
       object.deleteInBackground();
    } else {
      // something went wrong
    }
  }
});
```

If you need more info, go to: https://parse.com/docs/android/guide

Answer (score 0):

```
private EditText txtDescription = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription)

   String string = txtDescription.getText().toString();
```

**Parse Object :**

Storing data on Parse is built around the ParseObject. Each ParseObject contains key-value pairs of JSON-compatible data. This data is schemaless, which means that you don't need to specify ahead of time what keys exist on each ParseObject. You simply set whatever key-value pairs you want, and our backend will store it.

https://parse.com/docs/android/guide

Answer (score 0):

```
String userName= edittext.getText().toString();
```

If **userName** contains multiple rows in parse,

To delete one by one use below code,

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("your table name");
query.whereEqualTo("table_coloumn_name", userName);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
       @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            for (ParseObject object : objects) {
                try {
                       object.delete();
                       object.saveInBackground();
                    } catch (ParseException exe) {
                          exe.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
         }
    });
```

To delete all rows use below code,

```
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("your table name");
 query.whereEqualTo("table_coloumn_name", userName);
 query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
       @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
     ParseObject.deleteAllInBackground(objects, new DeleteCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    Log.d("delted", "success");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```